# Need to notify the email send status after the http response is launched

Tags: html, email, go, websocket

I am creating a web app.(Front-End:html,Back-End: golang)

In one of the pages the app needs to send email to lots of people.Since it takes huge amount of time and i dont want to user to wait,i use go-routine for the function which sends the email.So before the function ends, the response is launched.

The problem is i need to show the result of these emails(Email Send Success or Failure) on the page where the user is currently visiting like a notification.

I tried web socket but since the user will be traversing different pages the socket is closing automatically.
Any idea how to do this.
Thanks....

Comment: This isn't Go specific. You need to check the batch email status after any page navigation has occurred. Whether that's just polling the web server or using sockets, that's entirely up to you.

Comment: You can use the very rudimentary approach of writing the results of the response to a particular file continuously, and read that file whenever you want to show the current status to the user. You can have the file named with something you can identity the client with. I would not recommend websocket usage just for this one case.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I tried to use sockets but the connection gets closed when the user traverses to another page.Am I missing something here?????.Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav Ojha .The problem is i dont know how to get the result as the response already comes back as i am using go-routine,the response don't wait till the completion of the email function.Unless i store the result in the server and call back server here and there to retrieve it back to the client.Is it what u r suggesting.But this will make lot of calls to server.Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll need to store the result and then check for the result if the page is navigated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if the user navigates away from the site then there is no way to send them any information. Browser specifically won't accept things that they themselves haven't requested. Now if the user is still on your site, then you can probably write up some javascript in the html page that asks the server every now and then for an update on those emails, then just pops up a little alert box when its done. Hope this puts you on the right path

EDIT: just read about sockets in go, may be what you're looking for.

Comment: yes.I tried using sockets but when the user traverses to another page the existing socket connection get closed....